# C# Webrequest to Sockets

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, httpwebrequest

I have an application that starts multiple threads, and each thread sends requests to a remote server. After profiling, I noticed that the most time is taken in sending & processing the request. This is the function:

```
    private string GetRequest(string url, string postFields)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Proxy = proxy;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.Host = Constants.URLDomain;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Accept = Constants.Accept;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers.Add("MyHeader1", "true");
        request.Headers.Add("MyHeader2", "header2value");
        request.Headers.Add("MyHeader3", "header3value");
        request.Method = "POST";

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postFields);
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        }

        string text = string.Empty;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream answer = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(answer, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return text;
    }
```

I was thinking of changing this code to use sockets so I could improve performance. Will there be actually an improvement if I change to sockets, and more importantly, how do will a sockets implementation of the above code look like?

Comment: _"in sending & processing"_ - first find out if it is spending the time in sending _or_ in processing.

Comment: It is the request.GetReponse(). When profiling, the time is spent in the System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive function

Comment: The using Sockets directly might not help much... But using WebRequest/WebResponse in an async manner may speed up throughput time.